# How to resolve EF Core migration error with HiLo?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

A little background. I'm using:

- .Net Core 2.2.3
- Postgres as my database
- Npgsql.EntityFramworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.20
- EntityFramwork as ORM

and I'm using that simple HiLo sequence declaration in my context.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo();
}
```

Which creates my migration files as follows:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        name: "EntityFrameworkHiLoSequence",
        incrementBy: 10);

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AspNetRoles",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo),
            Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
        });
    // other tables code goes here... All key has
    // .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo)
}
```

Everything works, but HiLo is assigning strange IDs (but still unique). How strange? Let me explain. For example:

I have tables

- Orders
- OrderItems
- Roles (completely unrelated to previous).

And I do a simple seed to database which assigns IDs as follow:

Orders:

- 1 MyOrder1

OrderItem:

- 2 MyOrderItem1
- 3 MyOrderItem2
- 4 MyOrderItem3

Roles:

- 5 MyRole1
- 6 MyRole2

So it looks like it have shared HiLo for all tables. I thought that It's HiLo per table.

Also I get error when I use clean new migration and do:

- `dotnet ef database drop && dotnet ef database update`

I've got error (translated to English from Polish):

`42P07: relation "EntityFrameworkHiLoSequence" already exist`

@UPDATE

Thanks to @jpgrassi I found solution for strange IDs. I've made named HiLo for every model. It looks like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)
        .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo("OrderItemsHiLo");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)
        .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo("OrdersHiLo");
    // More sequences goes below...
}
```

Now it all sound logical. But... I have new error:

`42P07: relation "OrderItemsHiLo" already exist`

My `Up` section:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        name: "OrderItemsHiLo",
        incrementBy: 10);
    // more code...
}
```

And in my `Down` section in migration I have:

`migrationBuilder.DropSequence(name: "OrderItemsHiLo");`

My question is:
Why this error is thrown on clean migration and how to get rid of it?

@UPDATE

I just removed that line and it resolved my second issue. Stupid me...

```
_context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using PostgreSQL with EF, but what happens instead of adding `ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo` broadly like that, you add it for each separated entity? Also, not sure about that call to `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`. It's not specified in the docs http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html#hilo-autoincrement-generation

Comment: Hmm... I never though of that. I will try and let you know :)

Comment: Error still occurs, migration file looks the same, all tests passed and basically everyhing is the same as using `modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo();`. Also I need `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` for Identity

Comment: The migration problem: What it is done in the `Down` migration? Is the `EntityFrameworkHiLoSequence` dropped as well? Now the identity generation I have no idea..  but what you mean you need it for Identity? By identity you mean, identity column? If so, then why you need the HiLo sequence? Little bit confused now.

Comment: @jpgrassi First thing, I've updated my question. Second, by Identity I mean [Microsoft Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). Sorry for mental shortcut Third, thanks for your help. You partial solved my problem.

Comment: Instead of running the migrations automatically try getting the SQL script generated for you: run `dotnet ef migrations script  <hilo sequence migration> <older migration> -o migration.sql` and see what's the SQL generated. There's clearly some problem of it not dropping the sequence. Maybe it's not in the same schema as the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192765/discussion-between-morasiu-and-jpgrassi).

Comment: I added an answer so others can benefit as well. Take a look at it, and also at the sample app I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though OP edited the post and pretty much solved the issue with my help, I'll post an actual answer so others running into the same "issue" can benefit.

Regarding the "strange" Id's generated. You need to create one sequence per entity, so they don't "share" ids. More on the provider documentation: [HiLo Autoincrement Generation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html#hilo-autoincrement-generation)

Override the `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext` class and add this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)
        .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo($"Sequence-{nameof(OrderItem)}");

// same for others you want a sequence
```

Re-add the migrations and you should have something like this:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "Sequence-OrderItem",
                incrementBy: 10);

// Order entity code ommited
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo)
```

Now regarding your "second" question, about not being able to re-create the database after running `dotnet ef database drop` I was unable to reproduce it. I created a sample ASP.NET Core App which uses EF Core with PostegreSQL and I was able to drop/create the db normally.

I pushed the app to my GitHub account, so you can clone it and try it yourself: [efcore-postgres-hilo-sequence](https://github.com/joaopgrassi/efcore-postgres-hilo-sequence)